# Multi-provider authentication layman terms

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to understand what the library `OmniAuth` does so first I want to see if I understand "multi-provider authentication" correctly. Does this just mean that your app can use either facebook, or google as different types of providers to authenticate you as a user? Thus you can login into your app by providing your facebook id/pw OR your google id/pw and both will take you to the same account under your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's kinda late but, yes, you were correct. `OmniAuth` is meant to offer more options for your users to register and authenticate themselves by leveraging other auth providers. In a simple situation, the process can be describe this way:

1. You register your app at the provider site. So they know who you are. They normally will require a redirect url, which is where they will send the auth response back to later on.
2. You get an app_id and app_secret.
3. When user click on "Sign in with ...", it take them to their auth url (the link often have your app_id and redirect url as paramaters)
4. User said, ok, I authorize this app to do these things. The provider send you back the authorization code.
5. Now your app can confidently go to talk with the provider. Hey provider, I am this app (show app_id and app_secret) and this user has authorized me (show authorization code). The provider now send you back the success auth data (which contains tokens, `uid` and other information)
6. In a server-side flow your app can then check the `uid` to see if match any user in your system (suppose you have a `auth_providers` table that link to `user`). If it does, sign that user in, if not sign that user up.

Most of the time you would want user to use only one auth provider (either Facebook or Google, or something else). Using both can result in 2 separate accounts. Of course you can find a way to get around that, like detecting if the email return from `auth` data has already been used, but that is not reliable, cause it only works if user register both Google and Facebook with the same email. It's up to you to find a solution to deduplicate those, should you want to let user sign in with multiple providers at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but in step 4, why does the provider have to send an authorization code? Why can't it just send the uid and other information after the user signs in thru them? It seems repetitive for the provider to send the authorization code to my app and then my app to send it back to the provider along with my app_id and app_secret.

Comment: What I described above is the Authorization Grant Type of OAuth 2 protocol. The Implicit Grant Type works exactly as you describe. The difference is about your app_secret. **Authorization Grant Type** is recommended if you have way to secure your app secret (e.g having a web server). The authorization process does not involve providing your secret. Only the second trip your server make have secret inside. It's more secure because of the double check. Access tokens gotten this way are long live (e.g 60 days). **Implicit Grant Type** is normally for SPA without server, Tokens are short live (2h)

Comment: What's wrong with sending the app id and app secret at once in step 3?

Comment: Because that would risk having your secret exposed when directing the user to the provider authorization page. And the extra security is from keeping your secret, well, secret. Only your server know about it.